# What prevents this Microsoft Access 2016 query from being updatable?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

The question is simply, what do I need to change in order to make this query updatable? 
[image: (https://imgur.com/a/Y5ARwni)]

For those more comfortable with SQL, this is what the graphic represents:

```sql
SELECT tblAnswers.[Case Number], tblAnswers.Set, 
        tblAnswers.[Q#], tblAnswers.Level, tblAnswers.Position, 
        tblAnswers.Answer, tblQuestions.Question
FROM (tblAnswers 
INNER JOIN tblSets ON 
    (tblAnswers.Position = tblSets.Position) AND 
    (tblAnswers.Level = tblSets.QLevel) AND 
    (tblAnswers.[Q#] = tblSets.QNum) AND 
    (tblAnswers.Set = tblSets.SetName)) 
INNER JOIN tblQuestions ON 
    tblSets.Q_ID = tblQuestions.Q_ID
WHERE (((tblAnswers.[Case Number]) Is Not Null) AND 
    ((tblAnswers.Position)>400))
ORDER BY tblAnswers.[Case Number], tblAnswers.Set, tblAnswers.[Q#], tblAnswers.Position;
```

As you can probably guess, it's part of a questionnaire-type db app. It needs to display a number of informational fields including, naturally, the Question from tblQuestions but only needs to capture the tblAnswers.Answer.

I'm trying not to cloud the issue by including irrelevant information (noise). The tables shown have the same relationships defined in the relationship window. One possible hint/definite annoyance is that I can't set them to enforce relational integrity. Maybe whatever is preventing that is keeping the query from being updatable.

Comment: [How to troubleshoot errors that may occur when you update data in Access queries and in Access forms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328828/how-to-troubleshoot-errors-that-may-occur-when-you-update-data-in-acce)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - how do you think that article applies to this situation?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - this article is at least relevant, but which rule do you think I'm violating? I've looked at the article many times and I don't see anything I'm doing on that list.

Comment: Breezed through without reading the whole thing, sorry about that.

Comment: In the graphic view of your query click Update button in query type section and fill in the values you want to update than switch to SQL view if you need the sql string.

Comment: Maybe`tblAnswers.Level`is not part of an unique index (and not part of PK)! Seems to be missing in my link above, but look at https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html or http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html. Simply found by searching for "ms access query not updateable".

Comment: Thanks, @ComputerVersteher. I'll double-check that. I'll take a look at the links you provided, too, but if they were that easy to find, I'm sure I've seen them already. SO is my last resort, not my first :-)